# Regex HHmm validation- Java

Tags: java, regex, string, validation, time

I need to validate a textBox entry which contains time.

Time should be in HH:mm format and in 24-hour format.

For eg:

```
09:00, 21:00, 00:00, etc.,
```

Invalid entries:

```
2534, 090, *7&**, etc.,
```

If time entered is in HHmm format, then I need to append a ':'
 to the entry.

For e.g:

```
If textBox entry= 0930, it should be changed to 09:30
```

This is what I have so far:

```
String textBoxVal = getTextBoxValue();
String colonCheck = ":";

if (!textBoxVal.contains(colonCheck)){
textBoxVal = textBoxVal.substring(0,2) + ":" + textBoxVal.substring(2,4);
}
```

But as is obvious, this code isn't going to work for all cases.

I'm not very familiar with regex, so any help on how this can be achieved using regex in Java, would be helpful!Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you do not use RegEx to handle this task. Use whatever classes provided by Java for validation. I think the class you are looking for is `DateFormat`. See the `parse` method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution using DateFormat, as pointed by Ranhiru

```
    String theTime = "23:55";

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); //HH = 24h format
    dateFormat.setLenient(false); //this will not enable 25:67 for example
    try {
        System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(theTime));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid time "+theTime, e);
    }
```

Comment: @rogelware The validation fails if the user gives the input as 22:45& or 23:23(  etc.

Answer (score 3):

The following will do the trick for you

```
str = str.replaceAll("([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):?([0-5]\d)", "$1:$2");
```

This will change 2300 to 23:00 and leave 23:00 as is.

You can also use `(?:[01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):?[0-5]\d` just for validation.

Just a further note - even though this one does the trick, if it is date validation that you want, then I would go the `DateFormat` route.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.But in my case, 24:00 or 2400 happens to be an invalid entry as well. It should be 00:00

Comment: Oh I missed that, sorry mate.. I'll edit my expression, it's an easy fix

Comment: @rogelware was faster than me :) Cheers buddy

Comment: +1.Thank you.But, I agree with you..it is better to use DateFormat.Used rogelware's approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming text to match is in var mytext
var re=new RegExp(/^(\d\d):{0,1}(\d\d)$/);
var match=re.exec(mytext);
if (!match) alert("Bad value!");
else mytext=match[1]+':'+match[2];
```

Comment: -1: Java, not Javascript sollution. This sollution does not check 25:34 as invalid entry.

Comment: Ah - I misread the question: Not JavaScript, but Java ... well, shit happens.